# Calculating MSE of the estimate $T=\max\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\}$ of $\theta$.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

The variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots X_n$ are i.i.d uniform distributed on $[0,\theta]$. $$T=\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$$ is the estimate of $\theta$.
I need to calculate MSE.

I know that

$$\mathrm{MSE}(T)=\mathbb E[(T-\theta)^2]$$ and so

$$\mathrm{MSE}(T)=\mathrm{Var}(T)-(\mathbb E[T]-\theta)^2$$ but I can't calculate $$\mathbb E[\max\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\}]$$ and $$\mathrm {Var}(\max\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\}).$$

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Note that $T$ is the [first order statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) of the sample $\{X_1,X_2,\cdots,\ X_n\}$

Comment: Every time a maximum is involved, considering events of the form $[T\leqslant t]$ helps. Here $[T\leqslant t]=\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^n[X_k\leqslant t]$ hence $P(T\leqslant t)=$ $____$, which implies that the PDF of $T$ is $f_T(t)=$ $____$. Now, $E((T-\theta)^2)=\int_0^\theta(t-\theta)^2f_T(t)dt=$ $____$ hence you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to consider that $X_i / \theta \sim$ uniform$(0, 1)$, and the maximum of an i.i.d. sample of uniform random variables is beta distributed, which you can verify by directly calculating $P(\max( U_1, \ldots , U_n) \leq x) = P(\cap_{i=1}^{n} U_i \leq x) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} P(U_i \leq x) = x^n$.  You can use this fact to get both $\text{E}[\max (X_1 , \ldots , X_n)]$ and $\text{Var}[\max (X_1 , \ldots , X_n)]$ without too much trouble using known properties of the beta distribution.